# 30 second countdown timer to exe script or file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

i have an php file that runs when it get call from internet, it catches data from http request and stores in Mysql DB. It runs in background
I would like to add an countdown timer in that that IF one state in my system isnt true it runs one script, and If it is true it runs another. 
I would prefer something server side.

MY php file:

```
require("config.php");

$doors=$_GET['doors'];

if (func == true) {
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $query = "INSERT INTO `futelldus_doors`(`id`, `event`, `date`, `time`) VALUES ('','$doors',NOW(),NOW())";
    mysql_query($query);

    mysql_close();
} else {
    // Run timer 30 seconds countdown and then run another script or function 
}
```

Its the countdown function i cant figure out!
How do i get such function to my file/script?

Comment: Well `sleep(30);` would probably do it. But are you sure this is what you want? As the calling browser would just site there for 30 seconds? Maybe it would be better to add a row to a ToDo table and create a cron job that runs every 30 seconds that queries the ToDo table for things to do.

Comment: Do i use sleep(30) after "else" and my script function after that. It doesent matter if calling browser get on hold. I try that, thanks